# Regex remove 1-2 character sequences: hyphens literal, not word boundaries

Tags: r, text-mining, regex

I need a regex in R to exclude 1 or 2-character words, but which does not treat hyphens as word boundaries.  Here is an example:

```
z <- c("regulatory protein SR-B1 na na na na", "Dr Foo is na Editor-in-chief", "na P3 protein is popular na na")
```

The intended '**gsub**' would produce the result

> [1] "regulatory protein SR-B1" " Foo Editor-in-chief"     "P3 protein  popular"

This is not produced from the **gsub** statements below. Instead:

A - 2-character segments unintentionally dropped from hyphenated words (and hyphens kept).

B - 2-character segments unintentionally dropped within hyphenated words (hyphens also dropped):

C - Produces: Error: '-' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""
*\b[[-"

D - Nothing dropped or changed:

```
gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", z) # A

gsub(" *\\b[-[:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", z)  # B

gsub(" *\\b[[\-][:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", z)  # C

gsub(" *\\b[[\\-][:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", z) # D
```

Input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
gsub(" *\\b(?<!-)\\w{1,2}(?!-)\\b *", " ", z, perl=T)
```

Comment: This really helped, and provided the syntax frame I needed.  I need to exclude 1 or 2 'alpha-character' words 
(e.g, 'na') and keep 2 character 'alphanumeric' words (e.g., 'P3'), as in the desired output example above.  
The substitution of '[[:alpha:]]' for '\\w' in the statement you provide, does the trick.  Decoding your 
syntax taught me about 'Negative lookbehind' in regex, which is super useful.  I learned something today.
> gsub(" *\\b(?<!-)[[:alpha:]]{1,2}(?!-)\\b *", " ", z, perl=T)

Comment: good to hear it helped ,but no idea why this is downvoted :) . Perhaps putting downvote for new joinees seems to be the tradition